# def loop(start, stop, step): not return expected value

Tags: python

We have this python code exercise and when it is run, the expected output for print(loop(-1,-2,0)) returns empty when it should be -1. Can anyone help, how this code can be improved to return that -1 output? Thank you very much.

```py
def loop(start, stop, step):
    return_string = ""
    if step == 0:
        step = 1
    if step > 1:
        step = abs(step) * -1
    else:
        step = abs(step)
    print(step)
    for count in range(start, stop, step):
        return_string += str(count) + " "
    return return_string.strip()
```

Comment: Can you show us other examples? What do you expect exactly?

Comment: for example: If print(loop(11,2,3)) it will return 11 8 5 which is fine. But if print(loop(-1,-2,0)) it returns nothing when it should have been -1.

Comment: You make `step` into negative value only when `step` was bigger than `1`. So, if you give `0` for `step`, `step` will be `1`. Empty result is normal.

Comment: number `-1` is bigger than `-2`. So there is nothing to loop in `loop(-1, -2, 0)` since it is equivalent with `loop(-1, -2, 1)`.

Comment: I'm a little confuse, if step is 0, shouldn't it change to 1 or -1?

Comment: You are changing `0` to `1` not `-1`. `range(-1, -2, 1)` has no elements to iterate.

Comment: I see. It get it now. Thank you very much Boseong Choi.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me :

```
def loop(start, stop, step):
    return_string = ""
    if step == 0:
        step = 1
    if start > stop:
        step = abs(step) * -1
    else:
        step = abs(step)
    for count in range(start, stop, step):
        return_string += str(count) + " "
    return return_string.strip()
```